# Better way to refer to repeat parents when dealing with select children in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a better way to write the following?

```
.parent .child_1, .parent .child_2, .parent .child_N {}
```

The case being i might only want to effect selected children, not all of them?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing sample html. Is there anything common about the elements you want to select? Same element type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the children can all have multiple classes, I would just do

```
.parent .child { ... }
```

And write the html as such:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child child_1"></div>
    <div class="child child_2"></div>
    <div class="child child_3"></div>
    ...
    <div class="child child_N"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can write you code in a CSS precompiler language, like LESS (http://lesscss.org/), which makes such things easier.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution without altering your html, you could use a css attribute selector.

```
.parent [class*=child] {}
```

The preceeding selector would apply to any child element whose class contains the text `child`.

Supported by all modern browsers. (ie7 and above). Check [This](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attributeAdvanced.html)

Answer (score 1):

With a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), you can use nesting:

```
.parent {
    .child_1, .child_2, .child_N {

    }
}
```

If you happen to only need to support Firefox/WebKit browsers, you could use [`:-moz-any()`](http://dbaron.org/log/20100424-any) and `:-webkit-any`:

```
.parent :-moz-any(.child_1, .child_2, .child_N) {

}
.parent :-webkit-any(.child_1, .child_2, .child_N) {

}
```

Also: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-selectors4-20110929/#matches

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent:nth-child(2n+1) {
  declarations
}
```

maybe :)

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/understandingnthchildexpressions